# Laravel api to check record failes

Tags: laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to query the database to check if phone number exist.But when i do so and test with postman it failed.
 Here is a sample code:

```
public function mobile_availability(Request $request ){
 $number=customer::where('phone_number',$request->phone)->first();
 if($number) {  

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'Mobile Number is available',
        'data'=>$request->phone,
        'is_available'=>'true'
    ]);

}else {

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Mobile Number is missing. Please try again',
        'is_available'=>'false'
    ], 401);
}

}
```

I got this as results

```
500 internal error 

Route::post('mobile_number_availabilty',
'API\mobile_number_availabilty@mobile_availability');
```

Comment: Your code should work fine. `->first()` will return `null`, which will fail the `if($number)` test. When you say "it failed", what specifically do you mean? What error did you get? You need to provide as much information as possible here.

Comment: Show the route you are accessing please.

Comment: Check your logs then. Laravel logs every error to `storage/logs/laravel.log`. You're likely getting a syntax error with `if($number) {  {` (extra `{` there, no matching `}`)

Comment: [2020-01-02 07:21:21] local.ERROR: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\API\mobile_number_availabilty] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\mobile_number_availabilty] does not exist. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sloyds\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php:806

Comment: Have you removed `{` from your code ? it is causing the issue, it disturbs your class, you have an extra `{` in your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check it like this, it might help you dear. Let me know if you face any error. Also show your postman error that you are facing. And you have one extra `{` in your code, it might be giving error to you.

```
public function mobile_availability(Request $request){
 if(customer::where('phone_number',$request->phone)->exists()) {

    return response()->json([
        'status'       => 'success',
        'message'      => 'Mobile Number is available',
        'data'         => $request->phone,
        'is_available' => 'true'
    ]);

    }else {

        return response()->json([
            'status'       => 'error',
            'message'      => 'Mobile Number is missing. Please try again',
            'is_available' => 'false'
        ], 401);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you removed `{` from your code ? it is causing the issue, it disturbs your class.

Comment: you have the api url in api.php right ? and how are you accessing it in postman ? can you show ? route and url

Comment: Okay it is fine, do you have this line of code in your controller `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` ? below this line `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205241/discussion-between-drey-1-and-akhtar-munir).